# how to fetch value based from two table with help of another table using sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my sql schema:

```
Table 1: scan_1             Table 2: scan_2          Table 3: scan_detail

P_no        work            P_no        work           P_no       work_date
 1          YES              1          YES             1         2017/11/03
 2          YES              2          NO              2         2017/12/31
 3          NO               3          NO              3         2017/12/13
```

I want to count P_no from scan_1 and scan_2 where date range is belongs to scan_detail. 
I use this query to count P_no from scan_1 and scan_2, but not able to add scan_detail in my query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS pick FROM (SELECT P_no, work FROM scan_1 WHERE work = 'YES' UNION SELECT P_no, work FROM scan_2 WHERE work = 'YES') AS total
```

In above query i want to add date range from scan_detail like

```
  select count(P_no) from scan_detail where work_date >='2017/11/03' and work_date <= '2017/12/31'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a join with your union result set of scan 1 & 2

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS pick 
FROM scan_detail d
JOIN (SELECT P_no,`work` FROM scan_1 WHERE `work` = 'YES' 
      UNION
      SELECT P_no,`work` FROM scan_2 WHERE `work` = 'YES'
  ) AS s  USING(P_no) 
WHERE d.work_date >='2017/11/03' AND d.work_date <= '2017/12/31'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use join query to add date time and then apply the filter. A pseudo query is given below

```
SELECT COUNT(P_no) AS pick 
FROM (SELECT a.P_no as P_no, a.work as work, b.work_date work_date 
      FROM scan_1 
      LEFT JOIN scan_details b on (a.P_no = b.P_no) 
      WHERE work = 'YES' 
      UNION 
      SELECT c.P_no, c.work, d.work_date work_date 
      FROM scan_2 c 
      LEFT JOIN scan_details d on (c.P_no = d.P_no) 
      WHERE work = 'YES'     
      where work_date between date1 and date2)
```